# LINQ Groupby query on a single column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where I have a Job which has multiple tests which run at specific intervals. A job run generates a unique TestRunId which is a GUID, which is used to reference multiple results, basically grouping a particular run with a unique RunId(GUID).

Now the problem is that I need to select unique runs which have been generated, but my LINQ query picks up every run.

I tried something like this

```
 var testRunIds = ((from tests in context.testresults
                                    where tests.JobId == jobId
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        tests.TestRunId
                                    }).GroupBy(t=>t.TestRunId).OrderBy(t=>t.Key).Skip((pagenum - 1) * pagesize).Take(pagesize)).ToList();
```

But as I said, this query picks up each and every testResult. Not sure how I do this now. I tried Distinct(), but that too didnt work. Sample data below.

[image: Sample data]

Thanks

I believe the problem is that I have multiple TestRunId values as its essentially a grouping. Inorder to achieve what I need, I tried using (got using Linqer)

```
from Queries in db.TestResult
where
  Queries.JobId == 1
group Queries by new {
  Queries.TestRunId,
  Queries.StartTime,
  Queries.EndTime
} into g
orderby
  g.Key.TestRunId
select new {
  _ID = (int?)g.Max(p => p.Id),
  g.Key.TestRunId,
  g.Key.StartTime,
  g.Key.EndTime
}
```

But this works only for MSSQL datasource which is essentially a

```
SELECT max(id)[ ID],
TestRunId,
StartTime,
Endtime 
FROM dbo.query where jobid = 1 group by TestRunId,StartTime,Endtime order by StartTime;
```

But what I need is

```
SELECT TestRunId,StartTime,Endtime FROM testresult where jobid = 1 group by TestRunId order by StartTime;
```

for MySQL.

Comment: Looks like it should work, but you shouldn't need to create an anonymous object to store the `TestRunId`. Maybe just `where tests.JobId == jobId select tests.TestRunId).Distinct()` will work better?

Comment: I have tried that, but if I do not create an anonymous object, I am unable to access using a strong type. In that case, I need to do something like this  `...select tests).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x.StartTime).Skip((pagenum - 1) * pagesize).Take(pagesize)).ToList();` But this wont work. Same result. And neither does this work `...select tests).GroupBy(t=>t.TestRunId)).OrderBy(x=>x.Key).Skip((pagenum - 1) * pagesize).Take(pagesize)).ToList();` Again, same result.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? When you group by testrunid dr will be multiple records associated with that unique testrunid, Can you please show a sample output you are expecting?

Comment: I need a unique set of 'TestRunId'. The list should contain a distinct set of TestRunIds ordered by startTime. Its supposed to be pretty simple, but somehow this wont work, whatever I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me out. I managed to do this in a two step process.

```
        var testRunIds = (from tests in context.testresults
                           where tests.JobId == jobId
                           select new
                           {
                               tests.TestRunId,
                               tests.StartTime
                           }).OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).Skip((pagenum - 1) * pagesize).Take(pagesize).GroupBy(x=>x.TestRunId).ToList();

        var resultData = testRunIds.Select(testRunId => (context.testresults.Where(
            items => items.TestRunId == testRunId.Key)).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Great. If you're happy that is the solution you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
var jobs = context.testresults;
            var query2 = jobs.Where(x => x.TestID == 1).OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).Select(x => x.TestRunID).Distinct();
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ny9MZT).

Comment: Just now noticed your comment that you need the result ordered by startTime, updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for trying. But it doesnt help. I have added additional comments to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're possibly looking for this:

```
var testRunIds = context.testresults.Where(t => t.JobId == jobId).OrderBy(t => t.starttime)
   .Select(t => t.TestRunId).Distinct().Skip((pagenum - 1) * pagesize).Take(pagesize)
   .ToList();
```

Do the filtering and ordering first, then select the single field needed, then use Distinct() for uniqueness, then skip/take as required. Selecting the single field first then attempting to order or filter on other fields in the table won't work as those fields are no longer part of the query.

Comment: @Navyseal Did this help? If not, please let me know the issues/clarify the problem so I can tweak the answer.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks, but it doesnt help actually. I get a `The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.` error. OrderBy must be called just before Skip(). But when I do that, I get the same output.

Comment: The issue I think is since there is a possibility of having more than one record which matches testRunId, we need to make use of the TestRunId which has the Max(Id). Distinct doesnt work due to this.

Comment: Yikes. How about if you put '.ToList()' immediately after '.Distinct()'?

Comment: I tried to use Linqer which gave me this `from Queries in db.Queries
where
  Queries.JobId == 1
group Queries by new {
  Queries.TestRunId,
  Queries.StartTime,
  Queries.EndTime
} into g
orderby
  g.Key.TestRunId
select new {
  _ID = (int?)g.Max(p => p.Id),
  g.Key.TestRunId,
  g.Key.StartTime,
  g.Key.EndTime
}` but this works on MSSQL based DataSource, I am unable to use Linqer with MySQL as I am unable to find the driver in the ODBC inspite of having the connector installed.

Comment: that doesnt work man. I have tried that already and also ToList().Distinct().

Comment: In which case I am sorry I couldn't help on this occasion. Best of luck.

Comment: You might want to consider placing a bounty to get more answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty